# select avg from each group that has same value in one column and max in other

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, select

I've been trying to find the answer but looks like nobody had a similar problem to mine so I decided to post it here.
I have a table with 200 records with duplicate values in `fix_id` column, in column timestamp, each of the records has a value ranging from 1 to 5  and in the last column I got  the age value.
I like to select for each group with the same id in `fix_id` column holding at the same time max value in the timestamp column an average value for age column and the there is a tricky bit that the age column sometimes can have value 0 and in this case, I like to skip this value.

```
 fix_id   timestamp  age
  10         2        0
  10         2        2
  10         4        0
  10         4        1
  10         4        3
  5          4        2
  5          4        4
  5          3       10
```

so from this table, I would like to get this result

```
 fix_id    timestamp   age
  10          4         2
  5           4         3
```

So if there is 0 in the age column I don't want to include it when is calculating the average.
Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is an aggregation query with filtering:

```
select fix_id, timestamp, avg(age)
from t
where age > 0 and
      timestamp = (select max(t2.timestamp) from t t2 where t2.fix_id = t.fix_id)
group by fix_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set a condition in your query like:

```
WHERE age > 0
```

then you will miss a case where the max timestamp contains only `0`s in the column `age` and you will not get that `fix_id` in the results.
So use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t.fix_id, t.timestamp, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN t.age > 0 THEN t.age END) average_age
FROM tablename t
WHERE t.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM tablename WHERE fix_id = t.fix_id)
GROUP BY t.fix_id, t.timestamp
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/81Dfui7uvNZEsWd6wcCWhN/0).
Results:

```
| fix_id | timestamp | average_age |
| ------ | --------- | ----------- |
| 5      | 4         | 3           |
| 10     | 4         | 2           |
```